# $| f (x) − f (y) |\le c | x − y | ∀x ∈ \Bbb Q, ∀y ∈ \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, Prove that $f$ is continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

Assume that there exists $c > 0$ for which $| f (x) − f (y) |≤ c· | x − y |$ $∀x ∈ \Bbb Q $ $∀y ∈ \Bbb R \setminus\Bbb Q$

> **Question:**  Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Can someone help me with the proof?

Comment: If the restriction on $x, y$ hadn't been there, would you have been able to prove that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: What is with the "definition" at the beginning? That is neither a definition nor an assumption you should be making in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any two real numbers $x\neq y\$, either they are both rational, they are both irrational, or one is rational and the other irrational.

- If they are both irrational, there is a rational number $z$ between them, which gives us$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x) - f(z) + f(z) - f(y)|\\
  \leq |f(x) - f(z)| + |f(z) - f(y)|\\
  \leq c\cdot |x - z| + c\cdot|z - y|\\
  =c\cdot |x-y|$$
- If they are both rational, see above, but use an irrational $z$
- If one is rational and the other irrational, then you have $|f(x) - f(y)|\leq c\cdot|x-y|$ already

So we actually have $|f(x) - f(y)|\leq c\cdot |x-y|$ for *any* $x, y\in \Bbb R$. Now given any $\varepsilon>0$, pick $\delta = \varepsilon / c$, and you're done.

Comment: can you please explain me this move: c⋅|x−z|+c⋅|z−y|=c⋅|x−y|

Comment: @AvivLiberman We have $|x-z| + |z-y| = |x-y|$ because $z$ lies between $x$ and $y$. That makes the triangle inequality $|x-z| + |z-y|\geq |x-z+z-y|$ into an equality. Then we just multiply everything by $c$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ can be approached by a $(q_n)\subset\mathbb{Q}$ and a $(r_n)\subset\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$